# Why does Python execute functions randomly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Python version 3.x.
Currently, I am writing some sample functions to learn the language's way of working but the functions are not executing in order.

Here is my code:

```py
import sys

def goodbye():
    sys.exit("\n" + "*" * 43 + "\n\nGood Bye!\n\n" + "*" * 43+ "")
    return

def strPoint():
    func2()

def func1():
    print("func1 called...")
    return

def func2():
    func1()
    print("func2 called...")
    func3()
    return

def func3():
    print("func3 called...")
    return

strPoint()
goodbye()
```

What I expected to be displayed:

```
func1 called...
func2 called...
func3 called...
*******************************************

Good Bye!

*******************************************
```

But I get the following:

```
func1 called...
*******************************************

Good Bye!

*******************************************

func2 called...
func3 called...
```

Why is Python not executing in order and what do I need to do to make it do so?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get the expected output when running from the command line. Where are you running it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. In no way do I see it printing what you say it prints. As a sanity check I tested myself and it prints your expected results. Either there’s some trickery going on that we’re not privy to or this is not the exact code you’re running. Python is a simple language, it’s like a child, if you tell it to do something it will do it blindly in the order you tell it, if you have it bad instructions it will go until it can’t anymore. Please assure you are showing the full code and specify where the file is and where you’re running it from and what command you used.

Comment: I am using LiClipse

Comment: I'm guessing this is a buffering issue and the `print()` are buffered, but the `sys.exit()` is not.   Try flushing stdout and see if that straightens up your ordering.

Comment: Try running from command shell python <file_path> and check if you getting the same result.

Comment: @Umesh Everything works at it should in command line. Now i have more curious about this.

Comment: @RussSchultz you were right. It is all about buffering.